# How to revert my Ubuntu system to previous state before an update

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates, uninstall, software-uninstall

Yesterday I installed updates using

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Something seems to have gone wrong as my system is heating too much since then. The hardware is fine but it is a software issue. I want to revert this update back (return to the previous point before the update) as I suspect that it is the cause of the problem.

How to return my system to a point before the update?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the packages that were updated by referring to `/var/log/apt/history.log`

You can then attempt to downgrade the offending package(s) using standard package management tools such as `aptitude` or `synaptic`.  You may run into difficulties with dependencies, however.

[image]